# Nivel adecuado de respuestas para preguntas correctas pero básicas

Tags: discusión

He visto muchas preguntas que hacen usuarios que están empezando a programar. Por ejemplo:

> ¿Cómo identifico los caracteres que se repiten entre dos cadenas?

Asumiendo que el usuario que pregunta muestra su código y los avances y esfuerzos que ha hecho, y por lo tanto merece apoyo, he visto respuestas buenas, pero que creo son avanzadas para el usuario que pregunta.

Este tipo de preguntas normalmente tiene un enfoque didáctico para aprender a programar (se reconocen a leguas los ejercicios/tareas/prácticas) y creo que las respuestas también deberían ir orientadas en ese sentido. Por ejemplo, creo que es más conveniente una respuesta que muestre dos ciclos anidados para comparar cada uno de los caracteres de una cadena, contra cada uno de los de la otra, que una respuesta que indica que solo es necesario utilizar el método: `DevuelveCaracteresRepetidos(string cadena1, string cadena2)` que posee el lenguaje X.

En este ejemplo es cierto que el método indicado resuelve el problema, pero el usuario que pregunta no logra el objetivo que buscaba el ejercicio, de comprender el manejo de estructuras de control y de repetición. Y la respuesta normalmente tiene votos a favor de otros usuarios que si saben programar, pero del op no hay retroalimentación, no marca la respuesta como solución, ni comenta si entendió, no da señales. Es probable que se haya quedado en las mismas.

No digo que se tenga que reinventar el agua azucarada, pero cuando se está aprendiendo a programar creo que si es necesario, y muchas veces.

Claro que SO no es un lugar para comenzar a aprender a programar, pero este tipo de preguntas han sido, son y serán inevitables en el sitio (recalco, hablo de las preguntas que si muestren que el op se ha esforzado en buscar una solución, no del tipo "hagánme la tarea"), por lo que creo conveniente que se les de una respuesta acorde al nivel que la pregunta pide, no a un nivel teórico/práctico avanzado.

Así que mi duda es: ante las preguntas que son de tipo ejercicio/tarea y que si merecen la pena responder, ¿qué nivel de la respuesta debería ser el adecuado?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hasta donde se, lo que se intenta en esSO es **crear una base de conocimiento**, a partir de problemas concretos.

Bajo esa premisa, la **diversidad**, con distintos niveles/puntos de vista, es **obligatoria**; cada cual, incluido el OP, es libre de usar/valorar la respuesta que le resulte mas satisfactoria/curiosa/interesante.

En mi caso personal, me encanta *reinventar la rueda*, dando opciones alternativas a las respuestas, digamos, *mas convencionales*. Y soy perfectamente consciente de que ello implica *menor número de votos por respuesta* recibidos, ya que muchos de nuestros usuarios no buscan ese tipo de respuesta, ni están capacitados para valorarla; no obstante, yo *me divierto* al hacerlo, que es de lo que se trata.

Por lo anterior, considero que tu pregunta, directamente, *no es aplicable* a esSO. Si lo que se fomenta es la diversidad de respuestas (no duplicadas, lógicamente), no queda mas remedio que diversificar *el nivel* de las mismas. Limitar ese nivel conlleva limitar el número de respuestas posibles, que es justamente **lo contrario** de lo que el sitio y su comunidad pretende.

Resumiendo: escribe **tu mejor** respuesta a la pregunta. Siempre habrá alguien que escriba otra distinta, con niveles y puntos de vista distintos. Deja constancia de tu conocimiento, y, sobre todo, **pasa un buen rato** al hacerlo.

Answer (score 10):

Siempre es bueno recordar que, aunque las respuestas tienen un beneficio inmediato para la persona que hizo la pregunta, el beneficio potencial es aun mayor cuando tomamos en cuenta las personas futuras que encontrarán la página con el tiempo.

Con esto en mente, *a menos que OP especifique ciertas restricciones en cuanto a qué herramientas se pueden o no usar en la respuesta*, siempre trato de dar la respuesta que usa la mejor herramienta disponible para la situación.  En otras palabras, aunque el que pregunta es un estudiante, siempre trato de dar la respuesta con el código de mayor calidad posible para beneficio general de la comunidad.

Por otro lado, estoy 100% de acuerdo con @Trauma, que hay valor en ver una variedad de respuestas. Esto permite que OP escoja la respuesta que mejor se ajuste a sus necesidades. Pero también permite que la comunidad presente y futura vote a favor de cualquier respuesta que les sea útil.

Comment: Opino igual. E incluso, pienso que es útil añadir una respuesta propia a una pregunta ya respondida y resuelta, si es que tal información enriquece lo ya respondido. Al final la idea es tanto ayudar al OP como a una visita de google que viene con un caso de uso ligeramente distinto. Además, me parece mezquino el no compartir conocimiento sólo porque los 15 puntos ya tienen un ganador.

Answer (score 2):

Yo soy contrario a reinventar la rueda cuando el problema no es trivial. Mi filosofía como desarrollador es ocupar la herramienta adecuada para cada tarea (uniendo entre sí las piezas con mi código) por lo que sería poco consecuente, de mi parte, responder preguntas del tipo

- Quiero hacer un framework en PHP, por dónde empezar
- Quiero hacer un ORM
- Quiero meter toda mi data en un TXT y luego hacer consultas en él

Sería irresponsable no decir que es mejor usar un framework probado, un ORM probado y que existen las bases de datos para no manejar la data en TXT.

Me parece que las preguntas que se pueden responder con constructos simples sí es adecuado responderlas didácticamente. Incluso dar una respuesta ligeramente ineficiente si a cambio resulta más intuitiva.

Y, finalmente, creo que el 90% de las preguntas que he contestado son del tipo: "no funciona como yo quiero, qué está mal?" seguidas de 500 lineas de PHP.