# ¿Es exagerada esta oración en la sección "¿Qué tipo de preguntas debo evitar preguntar?"?

Tags: discusión, temática, centro-de-ayuda

Leyendo la sección [guía para formular las preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) del Centro de Ayuda, encuentro este párrafo:

> Tus preguntas deben tener un alcance razonable. **Si puedes imaginar un libro entero** que responde tu pregunta, estás pidiendo demasiado.

Me parece un poco desacertada la parte en negrita, ya que hay diferentes casos.

Por ejemplo, cuando se está empezando en un nuevo tema, se puede desconocer la profundidad de este y las preguntas serán básicas así hayan cientos de libros en el área. Además, si yo imaginara que existe un libro entero relacionado a mi pregunta, creo que simplemente no la haría.

Por otro lado, cuando tenemos algo de experiencia en un tema, conocemos mas detalles (como para hacer un libro), pero se nos olvida que cuando empezamos nuestro conocimiento de términos y explicaciones era limitado, y algunas preguntas los que buscan es eso.

Muy diferente es el caso de quien claramente conoce el tema y en la publicación pide respuesta a la pregunta A, pregunta B, pregunta C y Pregunta D, lo cual está claramente fuera de alcance y amerita diferentes preguntas o ya esta explicado en un libro

Hago esta publicación porque respuestas como esta a una pregunta, me parecen contraproducentes, no aportan y se respaldan con la guía antes mencionada:

> Se han escrito libros enteros sobre esto ... casi casi demasiado para una sola pregunta ...

> Página de la ayuda, ¿Qué tipo de preguntas debo evitar preguntar?, 3er párrafo: Tus preguntas deben tener un alcance razonable. Si puedes imaginar un libro entero que responde tu pregunta, estás pidiendo demasiado.

Answer (score 3):

Personalmente no me parece tan exagerada, de hecho, podría ser aún más exagerada: si necesitas un capítulo de un libro dedicado a responder la pregunta, entonces la pregunta es demasiado amplia (ya sea porque es dispersa/confusa o porque realmente sea un tema muy extenso).

Si una respuesta podría llegar a los 30.000 caracteres (límite para una publicación), normalmente eso es un signo de que o la pregunta es:

- Demasiado amplia, o
- Basada en opiniones, o
- Falta información para concretar el problema.

Pero definitivamente debería hacer saltar algún tipo de alarma... y de hecho lo hace: cuando una publicación se acerca a ese límite (ni siquiera cuando lo alcanza), los moderadores recibimos una notificación indicando que hay algo que no va bien.

Ahora...

Otro tema son los comentarios que indicas. Aunque esos comentarios están en lo correcto, creo que igual habría que enfocarlos de una manera diferente -especialmente si el usuario es nuevo en el sitio.

> Se han escrito libros enteros sobre esto ... casi casi demasiado para una sola pregunta ...

No sé si este comentario es una copia completa -los `...` parecen indicar que se ha eliminado algo- pero le faltaría añadir algo indicando que la pregunta es demasiado amplia y un enlace a "¿Cómo preguntar?" y/o "¿Qué preguntas debo evitar preguntar?"

> Página de la ayuda, ¿Qué tipo de preguntas debo evitar preguntar?, 3er párrafo: Tus preguntas deben tener un alcance razonable. Si puedes imaginar un libro entero que responde tu pregunta, estás pidiendo demasiado.

Este comentario es un poco "pasivo-agresivo". Aunque el contenido es correcto, el continente no lo es tanto y no provee ayuda/guía al usuario sobre cómo mejorar la publicación.

Comment: La pregunta *de la discordia*, por si a alguien le interesa: [¿Como saber cuando necesito rellenar bytes vacíos entre los miembros o al final de una estructura?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/254340/19610).

Comment: Mi primer comentario es un intento de que el AP se de cuenta, el solito, de que está pidiendo demasiado. Traducido al *andalú*, sería algo así como `¡¡ killo !! ¿ No te paese que te has pasao?`. Por su parte, la respuesta del AP, a mí, me sonó a *exigencia*: `Y por eso no me puedes ayudar con mis preguntas?`.

Comment: ¿ Debería haberlo cogido de la manita y llevarlo por un caminito de rosas hacia un mundo feliz en el que los deseos se cumplen sin ningún esfuerzo por nuestra parte ? **Puede**. Pero no lo hice. Ese comentario de respuesta suyo ... para mi significó el fín de la incipiente *relación*. ¿ Hice mal ? **Puede**. ¿ Lo volvería a hacer ? **Depende**. ¿ Me pasé de *chulo* ? Tal vez, aunque yo no lo creo. Y ya está. *Mea culpa* si me pasé de tono, pero creo que mantuve el respeto. Simplemente *copy/paste* un párrafo que alguien escribió antes que yo.¡ Ah, voté para cerrar !

Comment: @Trauma no te tomes los comentarios como un ataque personal porque no lo son.

Comment: Lo se, lo se. Simplemente, en ese momento y hora, me sentó ... *no muy bien*. Creo que justo acababa de llegar del dentista :-)

Comment: @Trauma yo también... y yo no no puedo poner la carita sonriente :-/

Answer (score 1):

Para evitar malentendidos por ediciones posteriores, *copy/pasteo* el estado de la pregunta en cuestión **cuando yo escribí ese comentario**:

> #### ¿Cómo saber cuándo necesito rellenar bytes vacíos entre los miembros o al final de una estructura?
>
> Sé que esto lo hace el compilador, pero me gustaría entender lo que haría el compilador por mí.
>
> Por ejemplo:
>
> ```c
> struct  MixedData
> {
>     short z;
>     char x;
>     char y;
> };
>
> int main(void)
> {
>     printf("%d\n", sizeof(struct MixedData));
>     return 0;
> }
> ```
>
> El tamaño de la estructura sería: 4 ¿Por qué dio ese resultado? y cuál sería sus posibles direcciones de memoria? También tengo otra duda, cuando tengo un array de estructuras es necesario siempre hacer algún relleno? Y también estoy confundido con los términos de "alineamiento" y "relleno". Lo que tengo entendido, es que "alineamiento" hace referencia a la forma como están ubicados cada miembro en la memoria y el relleno son los bytes necesarios para calcular la dirección de memoria del miembro que le sigue a un X miembro. No sé si estoy en lo correcto o no. También estaba viendo que el compilador necesita alinear la estructura para que sea más eficiente para la CPU, pero, ¿Qué pasaría si no lo alineará como se debe? Alguien me podría explicar algún ejemplo demostrando su ineficiencia?

#### A continuación, el último párrafo editado.

**Solo lo he formateado en lista**; No he añadido ni eliminado nada:

> El tamaño de la estructura sería: 4
>
> - ¿Por qué dio ese resultado?
> - ¿Cuáles serían sus posibles direcciones de memoria?
> - ¿Cuando tengo un array de estructuras es necesario siempre hacer algún relleno?
> - También estoy confundido con los términos de "alineamiento" y "relleno". Lo que tengo entendido, es que "alineamiento" hace referencia a la forma como están ubicados cada miembro en la memoria y el relleno son los bytes necesarios para calcular la dirección de memoria del miembro que le sigue a un X miembro. No sé si estoy en lo correcto o no.
> - También estaba viendo que el compilador necesita alinear la estructura para que sea mas eficiente para la CPU, pero ¿Qué pasaría si no lo alineará como se debe?
> - ¿Alguien me podría explicar algún ejemplo demostrando su ineficiencia?

---

**Sigo en mis 13 de que es demasiado amplia**, y no se ajusta al formato de `una pregunta cada vez`.

> Por otro lado, cuando tenemos algo de experiencia en un tema, conocemos más detalles (como para hacer un libro), pero se nos olvida que cuando empezamos nuestro conocimiento de términos y explicaciones era limitado, y algunas preguntas lo que buscan es eso.

Sobre esto, mi opinión quedó muy clara en esta pregunta aquí mismo, en *Meta*:

- [Nivel adecuado de respuestas para preguntas correctas pero básicas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1609)

> Resumiendo: **Escribe tu mejor respuesta a la pregunta**. Siempre habrá alguien que escriba otra distinta, con niveles y puntos de vista distintos. Deja constancia de tu conocimiento, y, sobre todo, pasa un buen rato al hacerlo.

¿Tengo yo que limitar mis aportes, porque el AP carece de conocimientos *de base* para sacarles partido? No, si lo hiciera así, estaría auto-limitando mi aportación al sitio, y despreciando a futuros usuarios que **sí** posean esos conocimientos mínimos.

Insisto: Esa pregunta es demasiado amplia, se mire desde el ángulo que se mire.

Comment: Hola, gracias por comentar aquí. No la considero "amplía", más bien "dispersa" ya que hay una serie de 6 preguntas que podrían ser ressmidas en 2 o 3. Además, cada pregunta en un post necesitaria compartir el mismo contexto así que no la veo divisible. Tampoco la veo amplia ya que el tema es muy concreto (Alineamiento y Relleno de estructuras en C), para lo cual no conozco un libro completo de esto, máximo habrá un capítulo. He visto blogs, descripciones de compiladores (la mayoria en Inglés, no he buscado en Español), pero creo que nada que se lleve más de 2 páginas si fuera impreso.

Comment: Tenemos *opiniones* distintas; la mía está clara: voté para cerrarla. La tuya también: publicaste una respuesta. Dudo que tu me convenzas a mí, o que yo te haga cambiar de opinión. Y aquí estamos, cada uno con su punto de vista. Eres libre de publicar esa respuesta de 2 páginas, y yo soy libre de mantener mi voto de cierre :-)

Comment: @gustavovelascoh Tener una publicación con demasiadas preguntas siempre tiende a que se pierda la atención a la pregunta de fondo. IMHO yo prefiero ver preguntas de seguimieto, es decir, primero realizo una publicación con la pregunta que enmarque todo y despues creo otras publicaciones señalando como base la pregunta anterior asi cada publicación tendra una pregunta como señala el boton para crear una pegunta: "Formula una pregunta".

Comment: @gustavovelascoh, una pregunta que consiste de múltiples otras debiera encendernos una "alarma" antes de responder, algunas veces podrán ser más o menos aceptables. En este caso además de múltiples, exigen, en cada caso, una importante cantidad de teoría. Estoy de acuerdo con Trauma que el alcance  es demasiado amplio. Como moderadores que somos también deberíamos intentar velar por la calidad de las preguntas, una forma es aconsejar al AP en como reformular su pregunta, otra más drástica pero totalmente válida es reescribirla en una nueva y auto-responderla.

Answer (score 1):

Me acabo de dar cuenta de que, en realidad, **no** he contestado a la pregunta :-O

Vamos a examinar como funciona el sitio, y veremos si el párrafo

> Tus preguntas deben tener un alcance razonable. Si puedes imaginar un libro entero que responde tu pregunta, estás pidiendo demasiado.

es o no aplicable, *exagarado*, o limitante.

SOes es miembro de la familia SE; como tal, se ha ganado (o se está ganando) una reputación en lo referente a **la calidad** del contenido técnico que contine.

Ahora bien, **todo este contenido es aportado de forma altruista** por sus usuarios. Por lo menos yo **no percibo retribución alguna** por aportar nada. Y, hasta donde se, los demás usuarios tampoco (*mods* aparte ... ¡ quiero una camiseta !).

Ahora, la cuestión que deberíamos hacernos es ... ¿ Porqué ofrecer mi conocimiento gratis **precisamente aquí** ? Podría tener un *blog* propio, o irme a otra página, ... o montar una empresa y *forrarme*. :-)

Y aquí está la *clave*: el [*componente lúdico*](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1623/19610) del sitio: el aspecto que nos permite *ganar* y *perder* **reputación**, medallas, y otros *caramelitos*. Es una manera de animar a la gente a participar y compartir su conocimiento. Poco que añadir, me remito a la respuesta enlazada.

Entonces, si aceptamos que uno de los motivos por los que los usuarios aportan **gratis** su conocimiento es el componente *lúdico*, llegamos al punto importante: **los votos**.

#### [¿ Por qué es importante votar ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

> Emitir un voto positivo a una pregunta o respuesta señala para resto de la comunidad que una publicación es interesante, el autor ha investigado, y es útil; emitir un voto negativo señala lo contrario: que la publicación contiene información errónea, no hay investigación previa, o no consigue comunicar información. Cuanta más gente vote en una publicación, tanto más seguros pueden estar los futuros visitantes acerca de la calidad de la información contenida en la misma – ¡y por supuesto los votos positivos son una magnífica forma de agradecimiento al autor de la publicación por el tiempo y el esfuerzo dedicados para escribirla!

Ya estamos llegando. Estamos de acuerdo en que un modo de *calificar* las publicaciones es **votandolas**. Sin embargo, y esto es importante, **solo se puede emitir 1 voto en cada pregunta / respuesta**. Y esto nos lleva al punto debatido:

¿ Como emitimos un voto en una respuesta que abarcar mas de 1 tema concreto y específico ?

- No podemos votar **por párrafos**, solo por publicaciones concretas.
- En caso de mas de 1 respuesta, donde una de ellas *abarca mas temas* que la otra ... ¿ cual es **técnicamente mejor** ? ¿ La mas extensa, o la mas breve/concisa ?

Aplicado a la pregunta origen de este debate, que por cierto, es

[¿ Como saber cuando necesito rellenar bytes vacíos entre los miembros o al final de una estructura ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/254340/19610)

- ¿ Podría limitarse una respuesta a solo 1 o 2 párrafos ?
- ¿ Como votaríamos una respuesta **de 2 páginas** ?
- Si alguien publica otra respuesta mas, añadiendo, por ejemplo, los detalles técnicos de una arquitectura con buses de datos distintos para distintos tipos de datos ... ¿ sería **técnicamente** *superior* a la respuesta ya publicada ?

Pues ya está. Estos son mis razonamientos y los motivos por los que creo que el párrafo en cuestión

> Tus preguntas deben tener un alcance razonable. Si puedes imaginar un libro entero que responde tu pregunta, estás pidiendo demasiado.

no solo es **correcto** y **plenamente válido**, sino que, a mi juicio, **aun debería acotarse mas**.

<sub>**Nota**: pese a todo este *rollazo*, el sitio **motiva** a publicar respuestas a malas preguntas ... siempre y cuando que sean **técnicamente correctas**. Existe la medata [`reversión`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/57/reversal).</sub>